# The text box is overriden by a span in my material form. Why?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made a material login and signup form for my website, like Google's (older) text boxes. The problem is that, when I write into a text box and then click beside it, the span overrides the textbox text, making it look not good.

Here is the link: https://b-o-p.000webhostapp.com

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Code snippet:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="on">
  <div class="group">
    <input id="tb" name="email" type="email"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label id="txt">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input id="tb" name="password" type="password"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label id="txt">Password</label>
  </div>
  <button name="btn-login" type="submit" class="formbutton buttonBlue">Login
    <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
  </button>
  <h4 onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'">Forgot password?</h2>
</form>
```

Comment: Post all relevant code here. We can't  easily help debug what we haven't seen.

Comment: Please give your post a descriptive title. All questions on the topics of CSS and JavaSrcript "need help in css and javascript".

Comment: Okay , thanks for telling me

Comment: While you are using JavaScript in your code, it is obviously not part of the problem, so you should probably remove the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `form.js` file is throwing a console error.

Add this **above** your current `<script></script>` tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit; [Plnkr Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/aooGZCdGGlhGVAkyWq4Z?p=preview)

Comment: No problem, i'm happy to help! Always be sure to check the development tools on the browser you're developing on. You can easily catch console errors, and it will help you debug the problem(s).

Comment: @ChristopherKhawand Remeber to accept the answer that works;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS pseudo class to check if the text box has valid input.

```
.your_password_input_class:valid + .your_span_class {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: It overrides it when it loses focus

Comment: What overrides what when what loses focus?

Comment: When the textbox loses focus , the span comes back on the textbox , either if it has text in it , and if it is empty too.

Comment: You can see it live on the link I posted above.

Comment: @ChristopherKhawand I think you posted that on the wrong answer... no problem though..!

Comment: Sorry for that :)